# Youtube API v3 .NET integration

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I have youtube api v2 integrated in my app. 
I have API key and I want to integrate Youtube API v3, but I get error 401 (Response status code does not indicate success)
at

> Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at     Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 377

This is relevant code:

```
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApiKey = "myapikey",
    ApplicationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YoutubeApplicationName"].ToString(),
});

var video = new Video();
video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
video.Status = new VideoStatus();
video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

using (streamVideo)
{
    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", streamVideo, "video/*");
    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

    await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. Code didn't worked because app was hosted on IIS. There might be problem with IIS accessing the folder inside %appdata% folder. Token  file is by default saved at %appdata% folder. I tried changing permission to that folder. I added Everyone,DefaultAppPool,I_USER,... but no success. There is also newer  version of Google.Apis (1.8.2) which allows full path ( `new FileDataStore(fullPath,true)`) `true` means full path, but there is bug even there. It was not possible to user that constructor, because I always get error. So I decided my app should use IIS Express( In fact I created new project with authorization code inside). Go to solution properties and set your app use IIS Express.

- Get cliendId (json file) from https://console.developers.google.com (choose web application) and set `http:// localhost:48372` (or whatever your app port use) for javascript origins and `http:// localhost:48372/authorize.aspx` for redirect url. You should also find on the internet how to make your port static). Save your clientId file. (This step you probably already did)
- As you use IIS express there should be no problem with AuthorizeAsync method. You will be promted to enter your credentials and choose your youtube account(or just choose account if you are already loged in). When you give your app permission you will be redirected to authorize.aspx. Your authorize aspx page should create new IAuthorization flow object with Client Secret property and DataStore proprty provided. Read code from URL using `code= Request.Params["code"]` and create `UserCredential` object.`HttpClientInitializer` property of youtubeService is of type `UserCredential`. Method you should use is something like var usercredential= `flow.SomeMethodWhichReceives("user",code,CancelletionToken.None)`. After that the file containing refresh token is generated inside your  `FileDataStore` folder you specified.
- When you have your refresh token you can do whatever you want because refresh token should last forever (unless manualy revoked). There is method which allows getting usercredential from refreshtoken, something like `flow.getAccessTokenfromRefreshToken("user","your_refresh_token_string")`

So, when yo have your refresh token and using method last method you will be able to access google youtube api. You also get possibility that other users upload to your youtube account using this aproach. If you are consered about content your users put on your account you can always make videos they uploaded private and change them to public when you verify them.

Some methods inside google youtube api require OAUTH2 authentication (get refresh token from client secret ->get access token from refresh token...),upload videos for example, but some like getvideos do not require. You can provided API key to your youtubeService conctructor instead of `UserCredential`

EDIT: There is also one more catch I forgot to mention (for those who thought this was all). When you give your app permission to access google api( just before you are reddirected to authorize.aspx), you will get error redirect_url mismatch, because there is somewhere in the url parametar `redirect_url` which does not match with redirect url  you provided in your ClientId json,(port was different,at least, for some reason). Change this parametar so that is matched with redirect url you provided in clientId json.

Answer (score 0):

The [YouTube API error reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#general) lists error 401 as being either `authorizationRequired` or `youtubeSignupRequired` (under the Request Context Errors heading). I'm not sure how you would determine the full error information - if it's possible to see the actual HTTP response from the exception.

Comparing your code to the [sample code](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/UploadVideo.cs), you don't appear to be passing an `HttpClientInitializer` value with the YouTube user's credentials. YouTube will need this to determine which channel the video is to be uploaded to.

Relevant snippet:

```
  UserCredential credential; 
  using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
  { 
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( 
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the 
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access. 
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }, 
        "user", 
        CancellationToken.None 
    ); 
  } 

  var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() 
  { 
    HttpClientInitializer = credential, 
    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name 
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I have to use HttpClientInitializer, but when I call GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync nothing happens. Program hangs,  no exception, anything.